# Как удалить пробелы и переносы строк самом тексте массива

Tags: php

Помогите решить проблему, есть массивы такого типа:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => 

                        1. 

                           Иванов Иван Иванович



            [1] => 

                        2. 

                           Иванова Иванна Ивановна



)
```

Задачи:

1. удалить пробелы и переносы строк от точки до первой буквы с пробелом между ними
2. удалить все и оставить только ФИО в массиве

Как удалять пробелы до и после текста я разобрался, а вот с остальным - беда :)

```
$data = array_map('trim', $data['Manager']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array_map(function($v) { return preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $v); }, $data);
```

при желании можно объединить:

```
$data = array_map(function($v) { return preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim($v)); }, $data['Manager']);
```

Comment: Зачем регулярки, есть для этого `str_replace`.

Comment: @And о боже, ну-ка покажите как вы на `str_replace` собираетесь это делать?

Comment: `/\s+/` достаточно. Не вижу проблемы в замене одного пробела/переноса на пробел.